# How to prove this property of parabola using geometry?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Tangents are drawn from a point A to a parabola. These tangents touch the parabola at points B and C. Now, if we draw a tangent to the parabola on a point D (on the parabola) such that it intersects AB at P and AC at Q. Then

$$\frac{\mathrm{AP}}{\mathrm{AB}}+\frac{\mathrm{AQ}}{\mathrm{AC}}=1$$

I proved this using analytical approach (Taking parabola $y^2=4ax$, and other points accordingly) and succeeded. But I tried lot but couldn't prove this geometrically. Can you please give me hint on how to approach this proof geometrically.

I am currently working and have proceeded this much.

$$\frac{\mathrm{AP}}{\mathrm{AB}}+\frac{\mathrm{AQ}}{\mathrm{AC}}=
\frac{\mathrm{AP \cdot AC}+\mathrm{AB \cdot AQ}}{\mathrm{AB \cdot AC}}=\frac{\mathrm{\dfrac{1}{2}\sin ({A})\cdot AP \cdot AC}+\mathrm{\dfrac{1}{2}\sin ({A}) \cdot AB \cdot AQ}}{\mathrm{\dfrac{1}{2}\sin ({A})  \cdot AB \cdot AC}} =\frac{\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta APC)+\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta AQB)}{\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta ABC)}$$

Therefore, what remains to prove is

$$\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta APC)+\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta AQB)=\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta ABC)$$
Which is same as proving
$$\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta AQB)=\operatorname {Ar.}(\Delta BPC)$$

Thanks.

Comment: @HariShankar I couldn't relate this problem to any of the proofs given on the page whose link you've given. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Theorem 3 on that page establishes $\frac{AP}{PB} = \frac{QC}{AQ}$. From this we can show that $\frac{AP}{AB} = \frac{QC}{AC} =\frac{AC-AQ}{AC} =1- \frac{AQ}{AC}$.

Comment: Its Appollonius Theorem, and not Theorem 3 :D

Comment: @HariShankar Thanks a lot. You can post this as an answer and I'll happily accept that!

Comment: You might be interested in this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489139/a-point-lies-on-a-dilation-of-a-conic-with-scale-factor-k-iff-its-polar-is-tan

Comment: It's related to conic section

Comment: @user471651 Sure I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments.  The comments can be paraphrased as:

> Apollonius' Theorem at [cut-the-knot.org](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Parabola.shtml) establishes
> $\dfrac{AP}{PB} = \dfrac{QC}{AQ}$.
>
> From this we can show that $$\frac{AP}{AB} = \frac{QC}{AC} =\frac{AC-AQ}{AC} =1- \frac{AQ}{AC}.$$
> – [Hari Shankar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/351559/hari-shankar) Sep 1 '17 at 10:35

An alternate link for this theorem by Apollonius is Dorrie's [*100 Great Problems Of Elementary Mathematics*, pg 220](https://archive.org/details/100GreatProblemsOfElementaryMathematicsDoverHeinrichDrrie_201808/page/n227/mode/2up).